# JavaScript - Put new data in LocalStorage on input change event

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am trying to develop a todolist with localStorage so when the users come back on the page the data from their lists is well loaded.
I have already the script to save to data and to load it when the page refresh but :

- This is what I want to do : I would like to refresh the data in the localStorage when a user change the value of an input (current tasks).
  To be honest I don't really know how I can do that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <?php include 'layout/head.phtml'; ?>
    </head>

    <body>

    <header>
            <?php include 'layout/header.phtml'; ?>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!--Add list name h3-->
                    <h4>En cours</h4>
                    <div id="tasks-container">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="new-task-container-submit">
                        <form id="form-add-task" action="">
                            <input class="btn-style" type="submit" id="new-task-submit" value="+" title="Ajouter">
                            <input class="input-style" type="text" id="new-task-input" placeholder="Ajouter une tâche">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="completed-tasks-container">
                        <h4>Terminées</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <?php include 'layout/footer.phtml'; ?>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

```js
let inputNewTask = document.querySelector("#new-task-input");
let tasksContainer = document.querySelector("#tasks-container");
let formAddTask = document.querySelector("#form-add-task");

let tasksList = [];
let tasksID = 1;

function genererTasks(){
    const listTasksJson = window.localStorage.getItem("Tasks name");
    const listTasks = JSON.parse(listTasksJson);

    for(let i = 0; i < listTasks.length; i++){
        
        let newTaskContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newTaskContainer.classList.add("new-task-container");
        let newTaskInput = document.createElement("input");
        newTaskInput.classList.add("input-style", "task-content");
        newTaskInput.id = "task-" + tasksID;
        tasksID = tasksID + 1;
        newTaskInput.type = "text";
        newTaskInput.value = listTasks[i];
        newTaskInput.textContent = listTasks[i].value;
        
        let iconDelete = document.createElement("i");
        iconDelete.classList.add("fa-regular", "fa-circle", "btn-style");

        tasksContainer.appendChild(newTaskContainer);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(iconDelete);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(newTaskInput);
        
        tasksList.push(listTasks[i]);
    }
}

//Generate the page
const listTasksJson = (localStorage.getItem("Tasks name") !== null);
if (listTasksJson){
    genererTasks();
}

//Listener add new task
formAddTask.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let taskContent = inputNewTask.value;
    if(!taskContent){
        alert("Veuillez remplir le champs");
    }else{
        
        inputNewTask.value = "";
        let newTaskContainer = document.createElement("div");
        newTaskContainer.classList.add("new-task-container");
        let newTaskInput = document.createElement("input");
        newTaskInput.classList.add("input-style" , "task-content");
        newTaskInput.id = "task-" + tasksID;
        tasksID = tasksID + 1;
        newTaskInput.type = "text";
        newTaskInput.value = taskContent;
        newTaskInput.textContent = taskContent.value;
        
        let iconDelete = document.createElement("i");
        iconDelete.classList.add("fa-regular", "fa-circle", "btn-style");

        tasksContainer.appendChild(newTaskContainer);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(iconDelete);
        newTaskContainer.appendChild(newTaskInput);
        

        tasksList.push(taskContent);
        window.localStorage.setItem("Tasks name", JSON.stringify(tasksList));
    }
})

// Listener to change text tasks and put the new data in LocalStorage



//window.localStorage.removeItem("Tasks name");
```

I tried with change event but the only thing I am able to do is when I change the value of one input, the entire array is replace with the value of the one (don't know if i'm clear)
I set id's on my input element maybe I can use it?

Comment: Please show what you tried to do in the `change` event listener.

Comment: The change listener should update the corresponding element in the `tasksList` array, then write the whole array to local storage like the submit event does.